# How to check if product is already in cart Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, customer-account

I have products with one quantity for each product. So, I want to disable the Add to Cart button if that same product is in the cart and change the text of the button to **Already in Cart**, **Go to Cart** and to Change URL to Cart. How can I achieve this?? I am using Magento 1.9.3.8

Any help/suggestion is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: See if help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670419/how-to-check-if-a-magento-product-is-already-added-in-cart-or-not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me in magento 1.9

add this code in list.phtml in product foreach section to check if product is already in cart or not

```
<?php $productid = $_product->getId(); ?>
<?php $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
      $product_in_cart = $quote->hasProductId($productid);
      if ($product_in_cart) {
        echo '<center class="in_cart">Already in cart</center>';
      }else{ ?>
        echo '<center class="in_cart">Product not in cart</center>';
      <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Oky here is code what i used and its working perfect May some one else can use it , i would not recommend to copy and past the complete code  you can edit alerts as per your needs , add this code into addtocart.phtml    in app/design/frontend/yourtheme/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml

Answer (score 0):

The quickest solution I can think of would probably be to simply to modify the addtocart.phtml tempalte (`app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml`) get the current quote (`$quote = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getQuote();`), get all the items from it (`$items = $quote->getAllItems();`) and put them into an array. Last but not least check whether the currently viewed product is within this array of items (`if(!in_array($_product->getId(), $ids))`).

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')); ?>

<?php $quote = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getQuote(); ?>
<?php $items = $quote->getAllItems(); ?>
<?php $ids = array(); ?>
<?php foreach($items as $item): ?>
    <?php $ids[] = $item->getProductId(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <div class="add-to-cart">
        <?php if(!in_array($_product->getId(), $ids)): ?>
            <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
            <div class="qty-wrapper">
                <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
                <input type="text" pattern="\d*(\.\d+)?" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Qty')) ?>" class="input-text qty" />
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="add-to-cart-buttons">
                <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
            </div>
        <?php else: ?>
            <div><?php echo $this->__('Already in Cart <a href="%s" class="button">Go to Cart</a>', Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCartUrl()) ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Drawback: tons of products in a cart *might* affect the performance (that risk should be rather small though, given the fact that you're just iterating through the products array once to get the product ids).

A more advanced solution would be to create an observer, for example on `catalog_product_is_salable_after`:

```
public function hideButton (Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

    $productId = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getId();

    $quote = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getQuote();
    $items = $quote->getAllItems();
    $ids = array();
    foreach($items as $item) {
        $ids[] = $item->getProductId();
    }

    if(in_array($productId, $ids)) {
        $observer->getEvent()->getSalable()->setIsSalable(false);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Information about how to create observers are available here on SE en masse.

Answer (score 0):

Oky here is code what i used and its working perfect May some one else can use it , i would not recommend to copy and past the complete code you can edit alerts as per your needs , add this code into addtocart.phtml in app/design/frontend/yourtheme/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml

getProduct(); ?>
__('Add to Cart'); ?>
isSaleable()): ?>
    
        isGrouped()): ?>
        __('Qty:') ?>
        
            getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />

```
    <?php $productid = $_product->getId(); ?>
```

getQuote();
      $product_in_cart = $quote->hasProductId($productid);

      if ($product_in_cart) {
        echo ' This product is already added in cart please go to cart for checkout [image] Go to My Cart';
      }else{ ?>

```
      <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>';
  <?php } ?>

    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
</div>
```